# Chinese characters are not displaying in php from mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on one project which uses multi-language content

http://school.rssas.org

Problem: Chinese characters not displaying in from database

Actually its working on local host with same database files. When i upload it on server charters are not supporting but same time working fine on local , i have tried all solutions related to database.

http://school.rssas.org

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

Also sometimes what needs to be explained is that the user is sending/expecting UTF-8 encoded data when connecting to the database, so MySQL thinks it's supposed to handle latin1 encoded data and converts it accordingly. Issue the command `SET NAMES utf8` after connecting to the db

Please let me know if it still doesn't work

Comment: Yes i try this content type and its working .. thanks